# Using multiple predictors in mixed-model in Python

Tags: data-modeling, mixed-models

I'm working in Python 3.6 using Spyder, windows 10.

I would like to be able to predict "Speed" using some predictors such as "level", "distraction", "target", etc. However, my data has several levels:

Participant 1: Session 1 (Level 1 to m), Session 2 (level m+1 to n), ..., 
               Session 20 (level x to z)

Participant 2: Session 1 (Level 1 to m), Session 2 (level m+1 to n), ..., 
               Session 20 (level x to z)

.

.

Participant n: Session 1 (Level 1 to m), Session 2 (level m+1 to n), ..., 
               Session 20 (level x to z)

For each level, I'm measuring Speed, Distraction, Target, etc.

[This how my data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDrXU.jpg)

So, I think the best model for my data is mixed model (random effects model) because the relation between my dependent variable (Speed) and predictors may vary across different sessions and different participants.

I'm new to python and I was wondering How I'd regress these in python, to get the mixed-models regression?

I think this is the code for only using one predictor:

```
model = smf.mixedlm("Speed ~ %target", data=df, groups=df[["Participant","Sessions"]]).fit()
```

What if I want to use multiple predictors?